# Posterior distribution of $\theta$ with prior Uniform $(0, B)$ and density $p(x;\theta) = e^{-(x-\theta)}$

Tags: integration, statistics, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, bayesian

I am trying to solve this problem from a past exam paper:

> Let $X_1, \dots, X_n$ be a random sample of size $n$ from the density:
>
> $p(x; \theta) = exp \{ -(x-\theta) \}, \qquad  x > \theta$
>
> In a Bayesian framework, assume that the prior distribution for
>   $\theta$, $\pi(\theta)$, is a Uniform distribution on the interval
>   $(0, B)$, where $B$ is a known positive constant. Determine the
>   posterior distribution of $\theta$, clearly stating the normalising
>   constant.

I know that posterior $\propto$ prior $\times$ likelihood.

Prior: $$\pi(\theta) = \dfrac{1}{B}$$

Likelihood: $$p(\underline{x} ; \theta) = \prod_{i=i}^{n} exp \{ - (x_i - \theta) \} = exp \left\{ - \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i - n\theta\right) \right\} $$

EDIT: Changed equality to proportionality in response to the comment below.

Posterior: $$ \pi(\theta \mid \underline{x}) \propto \dfrac{1}{B} \times exp \left\{ - \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i  - n\theta\right) \right\} $$

Now I am stuck. I know the posterior distribution needs to integrate to 1, and this is the way I can find the normalising constant. However, I am unsure about how to find the limits of the integration and how to actually compute this integration (I assume the integration is with respect to $\theta$?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minor comment: posterior is *proportional* to the product of prior and maximum likelihood, **not** equal.

---

The integration is indeed with respect to $\theta$. To find the limits refer to the definition of p.d.f., namely it's non-zero when $\theta < x$. Hence, 
$$
\pi(\theta \mid \underline{x}) = \frac 1 {\mathcal{Z}} \cdot \dfrac{1}{B} \times \exp \left\{ - \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i  - n\theta\right) \right\}
$$
and we need to find the constant $\mathcal{Z}$. Integrating one gets that 
$$
\int \pi(\theta \mid \underline{x}) ~d\theta = \frac 1 {\mathcal{Z}} \cdot \frac 1 {nB} e^{-\sum_{i=1}^n x_i} \int_{-\infty}^{\max(x_i)} e^{n\theta} ~ d(n\theta) = \frac 1{nB} {e^{n\max(x_i) -  \sum_{i=1}^n x_i}} \cdot \frac 1 {\mathcal{Z}} = 1 \implies \\ \mathcal{Z} = Bn \cdot e^{- n\max(x_i) +  \sum_{i=1}^n x_i}.
$$
Finally, the posterior distribution can be written as follows 
$$
\pi(\theta \mid \underline{x}) = \frac 1 {B^2n} \cdot \exp\left\{n[\max(x_i) + \theta] -2  \sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right\}.
$$

Comment: Thanks for your minor comment - I have updated the post accordingly. Thanks also for  explaining where the limits of the integration come from, that makes sense. Where do the extra $n$s come from e.g. in $\dfrac{1}{nB}$ and $d(n \theta)$? Is that just because we have $e^{n\theta}$ in the integral?

Comment: I multiply and divide by $n$, in order to make the integral look more friendly ;)

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for clarifying and for your help with this!